# pyrss2gen, syntax error

Tags: python

Here's what I have. I'm getting a syntax error with '])', and I don't get why?

```
import datetime
import PyRSS2Gen

jp = "Mokuyoubi"
en = "Thursday"

rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
    title = "Vocab of the Day - JapLearn.com",
    link = "http://www.JapLearn.com",
    description = "The latest JapLearn.com"
                  "Vocab of the Day!",

    lastBuildDate = datetime.datetime.utcnow(),

    items = [
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = "Vocab of the Day - Date",
         link = "http://www.JapLearn.com",
         description = "   Japanese: "+jp+
                       "Translation: "+en,
         pubDate = datetime.datetime()
    ])

rss.write_xml(open("japlearn-votd.xml", "w"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items = [
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = "Vocab of the Day - Date",
         link = "http://www.JapLearn.com",
         description = "   Japanese: "+jp+
                       "Translation: "+en,
         pubDate = datetime.datetime()
    )]
```

Close `(` parenthesis first and than close `[`.

As @levon suggested these things should be handelled by your `editor`. I personally use Vim with [syntastic](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736) for automatic syntax checking.

You also need to provide provide proper arguments to `pudate = datetime.datetime()`. Take a look at the example given [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRSS2Gen).

Your code gave me this error on execution.

```
  File "rss.py", line 22, in <module>
    pubDate = datetime.datetime(),
TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with the posted code:

1. There's a missing **corresponding closing parenthesis** for this
   statement

   rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
2. In addition as @RanRag points out, your `])` just below the line
   starting with `pubDate` needs to be **reversed to `)]`**

I would suggest using an editor that matches parenthesis (I use emacs) and some tools like pylint, pychecker etc ... to help with these types of problems.

Comment: @abkai .. is there no problem with the missing corresponding `)` for the `rss = ` statement?